# Change search result page to Single Page of Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have two search forms in my site one is for `blog posts` and other one is for `products` (woocommerce products). What I want here is I want to display the result of search for in the single page of related product like `Blog Post` search form result in `single-post.php` and `Product` search for result in `single-product.php`.

I have filtered the search using hidden input field,

```
<form action="<?php echo get_site_url() ?>" method="GET">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="search" name="s" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Products" required>
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="products" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                 <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I direct the search result to the related single page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add code like this in search.php

```
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if(isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
            $type = $_GET['post_type'];
            if($type == 'products') {
               get_template_part( 'single', 'product' );
            } else {
               get_template_part( 'single', 'post' );
            }
    } else {
            get_template_part( 'single', 'post' );
    }
    endwhile;
```

Comment: Smart answer. Thank you